# The fundamental group of a band

Tags: algebraic-topology

I need some help with this please, my problem is to find the fundamental group of a "band".I have the circular region that we obtain from taking away an open disk from a closed disk in R^2 and then identify in the "external border" the antipodes, and then   identify in the "inner border" the antipodes too, but separatly(i. e. the identify process on the the external and internal border), Well i have to compute the fundamental group of this quotient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This "band" is Klein bottle. To see why, use [this method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/474579/59552): closed disk minus open subdisk is homeomorphic to a cylinder, which is a rectangle with two sides identified. The linked question is concerned with the space obtained by taking a cylinder and glueing antipodes only on one end, not on both. The modification to an answer is very simple (just "color" the black side of a rectangle; well, you'll understand).

Then there are several methods to calculate $\pi_1$ of a Klein bottle, for example using Seifert-van Kampen theorem.